# How to make an android program wait to get input from the user?

Tags: app-inventor

I am currently working on a basic android app game that is something like this ["screenshot of the app here"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHt8b.jpg) (please ignore the numbers on the screen there is some problem yet to be fixed). The game basically is like this that the app selects a random number and the counting starts from 0 and each time a user can input either of the numbers from 1 to 4 and that will be added to the number on the screen and then the turn is switched to the computer so now the computer select a number from among 1 to 4 and that is added to the number on the screen the player that ends up on the number the game was chosen for, loses the game.
But here I'm unable to stop the program to get input from the user or say until the user clicks one of the four buttons. Also, I want to delay the computer's turn so that it looks like it is taking time to think.

(I can't really upload the code for this as I'm doing all these in MIT app inventor and thus it not exactly code but blocks placed together so it would be difficult to understand anyway as they are shuffled.)

[Image of the blocks of codes used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9Suv.png)

Answer (score 1):

In GUI apps (like Android, IOS, Windows Forms app) you do not wait for the user input on the console,you present your input options as buttons (1 -4) and  just bind an event to the buttons (like click) and when it is pressed, that is your input.  you can delay your CPU player using Timer to mimic the thinking.

Comment: Yes, I added the button as input options but I have to do that multiple time i.e. each time the turn switches form computer to human. (see the screenshot please, that may help)

Comment: why adding multiple times, just use a variable as mode, if it is computer, use a timer to mimic the thinking and invoke one button randomly (or as you wish) and then set the mode to user, this time, instead of invoking, wait for the user to press the button and add the number to the user stack (or as per your logic).

Comment: That's what the problem is, I'm unable to make the program wait for the user to press the button

Comment: can you please share the code in gitlab or something, pm me the details, i will look into and help you if i can

Comment: MIT app inventor is not really a code based, I mean here codes are already written in the form of blocks and we just have to place them in a manner that they work as per requirement. Still, I'm putting a link for the image of the blocks I used in the above section, please check that. Thank you.